# Compact Surface with Genus $1$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, surfaces

I am currently trying to solve a problem but have no idea how to go about it. The question reads:

> Show that a Compact Surface with Genus $1$ has points where the Gaussian Curvature is positive, negative and points where it vanishes.

Now, by an application of Gauss Bonnet for Compact Surfaces, I got:
$$\int_{S}Kd\sigma = 2\pi\cdot\chi(S)$$
Because the Genus of the Surface is given by:
$$G=\frac{2-\chi(S)}{2}$$
Obviously the Euler Characteristic of this Surface is $0$. But then the Integral of the Gaussian Curvature over $S$ gives $0$. I don't know how I can conclude anything from that, or if it even means anything in the first place. If someone is willing to help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

The question was wrong (with $g=0$). A round sphere gives you a counterexample. Try proving the statement for $g=1$, however. :) [You will still need to show that there is some point where the Gaussian curvature is positive. Then the rest will follow immediately.]

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but the question as written is still incorrect for a genus g = 1 surface, no?  For example, the flat torus would provide a counterexample, correct?  It would seem to me that if the question were modified and applied to compact surfaces embedded in Euclidean 3-space with the appropriate regularity condition on the embedding, then the statement could be proven for genus g = 1.

Comment: @THW: The question comes from a course on surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$. It's a standard question in DoCarmo, my own text, and others. (The OP is taking such a course and didn't provide the context.)

Comment: Can I say that because the Surface shares the same Euler Characteristic with a Torus, it is homeomorphic to the Torus, and thus shares the same Gaussian Curvature? (which can be negative, positive and zero)

Comment: It is homeomorphic to the torus, but, no, you can't say assume anything about its curvature compared to the curvature of the "usual" torus in $\Bbb R^3$. But you can still use Gauss Bonnet, and see my comment in the answer!  P.S. You should probably correct the statement of the problem?

Comment: Using the Gauss Bonnet just states that the integral over the gaussian curvature is $0$, I fail to see how I can deduce that there is a point where the Gaussian Curvature is positive?

Comment: For *any* compact surface without boundary in $\Bbb R^3$, you should have proved in class (or should be able to show) that there must be a point with $K>0$.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't remember explicitly learning this... But is this a Theorem? Or does it require proof?

Comment: Yes, it requires proof. You can find a proof in my text (linked in my profile). Think about putting the surface inside a giant sphere and shrinking the sphere until it just touches the surface ...

Comment: Ahhh.... I did learn this. The statement was that if you choose a point of the surface farthest away from the Origin and a sphere centered there, the sphere and surface would be tangent at that point and thus the surface lies inside the sphere, thus bounding the gaussian curvature of the surface below by the sphere

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, Ah, yes, of course.  Thanks for the clarification on the context.